# I'm not able to install openCV in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, opencv3.0, opencv

I tried installing opencv by going to setting>project>project interpreter but it is showing me error: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGCpG.png

Comment: I think it would be handy if you tell your python version.

Comment: @Mace python 3.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [opencv-python](https://libraries.io/pypi/opencv-python)

The latest version for python 3 is opencv 3.4.9:

Currently, builds for following Python versions are provided:

2.7

3.4

3.5

3.6

3.7

**So you need to install python 3.7**. PyCharm can work with multiple python versions so you *don't need to uninstall 3.8.2*

Answer (score -1):

suggests to install Anaconda, Add a New Conda Environment for your Project, try to install openCV through Anaconda, if still failed, pls try to change other repository. My repository is "https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/", and I succeeded installing openCV